# What does it mean when a str object attribute is "read-only?" How do I fix my code?

Tags: python, string, attributes, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Here is my code:

```
# Get the name of the file and open it
name = input("Enter file:")
handle = open(name)

# Count word frequency 
counts = dict()
for line in handle:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) + 1
        
# Find the most common word
bigcount = None
bigword = None 
for word.count in counts.items():
    if bigcount is None or count > bigcount:
        bigword = word
        bigcount = count
        
# All done
print(bigword, bigcount)
```

When I call it and input the message and press enter, an AttributeError appears and says:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-500085f286fd> in <module>
     13 bigcount = None
     14 bigword = None
---> 15 for word.count in counts.items():
     16     if bigcount is None or count > bigcount:
     17         bigword = word

AttributeError: 'str' object attribute 'count' is read-only
```

What should I do to fix my code? What is "read-only" str object attribute?

Comment: What is `for word.count in ...` supposed to do? `word` is a string object from the previous loop. That loop structure is trying to write to the [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) attribute of the sting object (n.b., methods are attributes), which isn't allowed. It's the same problem as trying to write `"test".count = 1`.

Comment: `word` is a string, if the first two nested `for` loops in your code execute at least once. A string has a method `count()` (for counting the number of consecutive times a substring can be found in the string) and by using `word.count` as your loop variable in `for word.count in counts.items():`, your code is trying to overwrite `.count` on `word`, which it can't.

Comment: You probably wanted `for word, count in counts.items()` though you should be careful about using and reusing variable names in different meanings in your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your example code: `word` is a string, if the first two nested `for` loops in your code execute at least once.

```
for line in handle:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        ...
```

A string has a method `count()` (for counting the number of consecutive times a substring can be found in the string) and by using `word.count` as your loop variable in `for word.count in counts.items():`, your code is trying to overwrite `.count` on `word`, which it can't. Using a period between two names is telling the compiler that you're trying to access an attribute on some object, more on that in [the documentation on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

To answer your question: this is not an error about a '"read-only" str object attribute', it's an error about trying to change a read-only attribute of a `str`-type object. A method like `.count()` on the `str` type cannot just be overwritten by something else, it's read-only.

You probably wanted:

```
for word, count in counts.items():
    if bigcount is None or count > bigcount:
        bigword = word
        bigcount = count
```

You should be careful about using and reusing variable names in different meanings in your code though.

Also, note that you never close your file (`handle`), you should look at using context managers (`with ...:`) and you're doing a lot of moving around of data for a task that could be done in a few lines.

For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

name = input("Enter file: ")
words = defaultdict(int)
with open(name) as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            words[word] += 1

most_frequent_word = max(words, key=lambda word: words[word])
print(most_frequent_word, words[most_frequent_word])
```

Of course this, and your own code, do not take into account interpunction, capitalisation, etc.